# Fill Color in rectangle depends on user input value

Tags: html, angular, svg

I am created an rectangle using SVG, i want to want to implement that the rectangle will fill the color"green" based on user input (the input was dynamic)

```
<rect width="50" height="25" x="60" y="656" class="fill-light-pink">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class to fill with color green and then put the class there depending on the user input

```
<rect width="50" height="25" x="60" y="656" class.fill-green={{isUserInputGreen}} class="fill-light-pink">
```